# Where can I specify my javadoc document charset?

Tags: character-encoding, javadoc

I'm writing javadoc in Polish language and I want to define UTF-8 charset for my javadoc documentation generated by eclipse - how and where can I do that?

Answer (score 9):

Right click on your project 
Export... > javadoc 

In the third panel, write this

> -encoding utf8 -docencoding utf8  -charset utf8

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There are three relevant options for Javadoc:

- The [`-encoding` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#encoding) indicates the encoding of the source files. This should be whatever your sources files are actually encoded in (and the compiler should use the same `-encoding` option). You can encode characters which are not in the character set of this encoding using the `\uXXXX` convention. (And there are some people which argue you should never use characters outside of US-ASCII in your source code, to make it portable. I think nowadays UTF-8 is fine.)
- The [`-docencoding` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#docencoding) indicates which encoding to use when writing out the HTML files. Characters which are used in the produced HTML and not in the character set are replaced by their `&#...;` equivalent.
- The [`-charset` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#charset) indicates what to write in the `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=...">` tag in the header of the generated HTML files.

There is virtually never a reason not to use the same value for `-docencoding` and `-charset`, and I don't know why there are two different options for them. Using a different value produces either invalid HTML or at least wrong characters.

Comment: `-encoding utf8 -docencoding utf8 -charset utf8` gives me `javadoc: error - invalid flag: -docencoding`. Only with only `-encoding utf8` I don't get an error. JDK8.

Comment: Hmm, no idea. I don't hava a JDK8 installed here, so I can't check this – maybe they finally got rid of the other options. [Oracle's documentation still has them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#CHDHDEAD).