# IDEA javadoc generator - ignore errors

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

When I trying to generate javadoc - I get some meaningless errors like encoding error in non-javadoc comments. Maybe exists some command-line argument or something for ignore errors and generate docs anyway?

Error example (It's even not in javadocs, just inline Cyrillic comment)

```
GroupsSorter.java:83: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
    //Р?С‚РѕРіРѕРІС‹Р№ СЃРїРёСЃРѕРє
       ^
```

Comment: Could you please show the exact text of the error you're getting?

Comment: @yole, sure. I'll update question.

Comment: You should use the proper encoding (preferably UTF-8).

Comment: @GáborBakos, unfortunatly, it's impossible :(

Comment: @Alendorff you mean you have to type the cyrillic letters with Latin-1 (Cp1251) characterset? That is quite unfortunate. In case you are using a different encoding, try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302881/where-can-i-specify-my-javadoc-document-charset

Comment: Do you use JDK7 or 8?